# Cannot read that as a ZipFile for .exe file C#

Tags: c#, extract, unzip

I'm using SevenZIP library files to unzip/extract .exe file. When i tried this approcah I'm getting a error  `Cannot read that as a ZipFile` & `zip exception was unhanded`. I don't want to use any 7zip.exe console app in my project & i prefer to use .dll files in my project.

Is there any other way to extract .exe file?

```
  private void MyExtract()
    {
        if(x86)
            ExtractZip(@"D:\22.1.2.702\64\953-win_x86.exe", ".");
        else
            ExtractZip(@"D:\22.1.2.702\64\.702-win_x64.exe", ".");
    }

    private void ExtractZip(string zipFile, string directory)
    {
        using (var zip1 = ZipFile.Read(zipFile))
        {
            // here, we extract every entry, but we could extract conditionally
            // based on entry name, size, date, checkbox status, etc.  
            foreach (var e in zip1)
            {
            e.Extract(directory, ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are there any API calls that accept a stream rather than the whole file? You either need to parse the .exe headers to work out where the last section ends (and so where the .zip starts) or search through the file until you find the [.zip magic PK\x03\x04](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_(file_format)) then pass the rest of the file to the API - or the .7z magic if you're using that format instead.

Comment: I was surprised that when i drag and drop my exe file into winzip and did extract manually, it worked without any problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code sample looks like you are using [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com) and not [SevenZipLib](http://sevenziplib.codeplex.com/). DotNetZip can only extract `.zip` files, not 7-zip nor `.exe`.

Comment: :In this linke there is an example to zip a exe file but there is no extarction o fexe file. <http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=CS-Examples>

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using SevenZip lib, try 7zip.exe in console. Use Process class to execute 7zip.exe.  It works perfect.

Comment: But he said he didn't want to do that, didn't he? Using the library would give other advantages e.g. streaming data in and out without having to write it to temporary storage.